# How to set a file size limit on FileUpload Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

When uploading a file, I get the error - out of size exception

I've added the code below trying to get rid of it! - written in vb

```
  dim filesize as string = FileUploadVal.PostedFile.ContentLength 
  If filesize > 1048576 then 
     des_label = "File is too large!"
  End if
```

But still getting the error, is there a way to set a file limit before uploading?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819583/asp-net-vb-net-fileupload-control) link may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file size would be greater then the allowed limit in web.config. You can set the [HttpRuntimeSection.MaxRequestLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to limit the upload file size.

> The MaxRequestLength property specifies the limit for the buffering
>   threshold of the input stream. For example, this limit can be used to
>   prevent denial of service attacks that are caused by users who post
>   large files to the server, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<httpRuntime
   executionTimeout = "HH:MM:SS" 
   maxRequestLength = "number" 
   requestLengthDiskThreshold = "number" 
   useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl = "[True|False]" 
   minFreeThreads = "number" 
   minLocalRequestFreeThreads = "number" 
   appRequestQueueLimit = "number"
   enableKernelOutputCache = "[True|False]" 
   enableVersionHeader = "[True|False]" 
   apartmentThreading = "[True|False]"
   requireRootedSaveAsPath = "[True|False]"
   enable = "[True|False]" 
   sendCacheControlHeader = "[True|False]" 
   shutdownTimeout = "HH:MM:SS"
   delayNotificationTimeout = "HH:MM:SS"
   waitChangeNotification = "number" 
   maxWaitChangeNotification = "number" 
   enableHeaderChecking = "[True|False]" 
/>
```